# How do I log responses from my Rails Controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, nginx

I have a Rails API which is currently used by a mobile app to perform database transactions.

The API returns an JSON object and I'd like to be able to log all the responses that each mobile app request returns on my Rails Server.

I've looked at lograge but they doesn't seem to have the ability to log responses from ActionController.

How can I approach this?

Answer (score 1):

You can log your responses right before sending them to your mobile application.
[See chapter 2.3](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html)

You will have something like

```
def your_method
  #do_something
  logger.info response_params
  respond_with response_params
end
```

Comment: Thanks! That certainely is helpful! I have a Rack::Middleware, Rack::ContentLength activated and I'm trying to find out the Content-Length. 

Using the method above, when I inspect response.headers, the Content-Length doesn't appear, is it because this response that its being output is before the appended header?

If so, how do I access that?

Comment: I think it is possible to use an after-filter in controller for that, which will log the whole response, and there you could access the headers already.